# Set ImagePickerController delegate

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am not sure how to initialize the UIImagePickerController. I cannot set the delegate. I would like to use

```
pickerController.delegate = self;
```

but this yields a warning: "Sending 'MyViewController *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'"

I declared my class to be a delegate (UIImagePickerControllerDelegate) and added this:

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController;
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error. You declared your class to be a `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, yes, but the picker needs you to declare as `UINavigationControllerDelegate` as well.